# Declare provision method of named in module dependency

Tags: java, kotlin, dagger-2

My project has following setup

```kotlin
@Module
abstract class CoreModule {
    @Provides
    @Named("text1")
    fun textOne() = "text1"

    @Provides
    @Named("text2")
    fun textTwo() = "text2"
}

@Component(modules=[CoreModule::class])
interface CoreComponent{
    @Named("text1")
    fun textOne(): String
}

@Component(
    dependencies = [CoreComponent::class]
    modules=[AppModule::class]
)
interface AppComponent()

@Module()
class AppModule {
    fun getStringDouble(@Named("text1") text1: String) = text1 + text1
}
```

Here I have 2 components `CoreComponent` which provides dependencies to `AppComponent`. Now I want to provide only text1 to `AppComponent`.

Since I have added `@Named("text1")` in `CoreComponent` to denote which string to provide to `AppComponent`. It forces me to use `@Named("text1")` in AppModule as well, which I don't want.

How can I create provision method in `CoreComponent` to provide only text1 to `AppComponent` in such a way, that I don't have to use `@Named` everywhere in `AppComponent`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can remove `@Named("<name>")` from Provider method in `CoreModule` and `CoreComponent`.

instead, you can create a custom Qualifier annotation like this

```
@Qualifier
@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
annotation class TextTwoName {
}
```

and do following changes

In `CoreModule`, use `@TextTwoName` in `textTwo()` for instead of `@Named("text2")` and remove `@Named("text1")` from `fun textOne() = "text1"`

In `CoreComponent`, remove `@Named("text1")` from `fun textOne(): String` while name function name textOne doesn't matter here only return type matters. it will take `fun textOne() = "text1"` from `CoreModule`

If you want to expose `fun textTwo() = "text2"` then you can add `@TextTwoName` annotation in the `CoreComponent`'s `fun textOne():String` method.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution would probably be to simply bind/provide it under a different key, a plain `String` in your example.

```
@Binds // bind it without any qualifier
fun plainText1(@Named("text1") text1: String) : String
```

---

If you do have multiple values for the same type then qualifiers would probably be easier to use in the long run though, since they allow you proper naming of the keys used.

Keep in mind that you can also create *your own* qualifiers and don't have to use `@Named`, it's just available by default.

---

An alternative to your setup altogether would be to use [(Sub)components for encapsulation](https://dagger.dev/dev-guide/subcomponents.html#subcomponents-for-encapsulation) which would allow you to only ever return the value produced without binding the whole component dependency.